# "разрешение на поиск устройств в Вашей локальной сети и подключение к ним" как вызвать и обработать статус на Flutter (для IOS)

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile

Требуется вызвать запрос на разрешение работы в локальной сети для IOS на Flutter, и после его подтверждения перейти на следующий экран. Готовых решений не нашел.

Из того что пробовал, это предварительно сделать локальный запрос, при этом вылетает данное окно с разрешением. Но данный вариант не позволяет отследить статус, если пользователь отклонил разрешение

[image: изображение взято из открытых источников]